# Number of Dyck paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,k_1)$ if allowed to go below the $x$ axis

Tags: combinatorics, integer-lattices

What is the number of (general?) Dyck paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,k_1)$, where $k_1\geq0$,  allowing the path to go below the $x$ axis and touch the negative horizontal line at $k_2\leq0$ an arbitrary number of times?

It seems to be equivalent to the number of paths starting at $(x_1,y_1)$ and ending at $(x_2,y_2)$ (all positive), where the paths are not allowed to touch the $x$ axis. Is it correct?

Comment: Is it allowed to go below the line $y=k_2$? If not it looks like one could add $-k_2$ to each path to get it as usual not going over $x$ axis, but this would change (raise) the start and finish points also, making it *related* but not identical to Dyck path counts. May be one can adjust those results...

Comment: @coffeemath No, $y=k_2\leq0$ is the farthest horizontal line it can get.

Comment: Did you mean that the possible steps are 1. go right 2. go up 3.go down if $y_1 > k_2$.

Comment: @arindammitra Dyck paths allow the steps: north-east or south-east. What you have is a Motzkin path.

Answer (score 1):

Wonder why nobody answered but the result is
$$
\binom{x_2}{{1\over2}(x_2+k_1)}-\binom{x_2}{{1\over2}(x_2-k_1+2k_2)},
$$
where $x_2=2n$ but in this form $x_2$ can be odd too.
It is an equivalent to the Bertrand's ballot problem -- just offset to the lattice origin.